# Bootstrap Progress Bar for MVC File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

Is there an easy way to show a blocking Bootstrap progress bar while a file is loading?

The progress is shown in the status bar in chrome as the file is uploaded:

[image: The progress is shown in chrome as the file is uploaded]

I'd like the dialog to look something like [this](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1)

[image]

My Action looks something like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel model)
        {
                using (MemoryStream uploadedFile = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(uploadedFile);                            
                    uploadService.UploadFile(uploadedFile, model.File.ContentType)
                    return View();
                 }
         }
```

Model:

```
  public class UploadViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Bleh.Web.Models.UploadViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home",
  FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @role = "form" }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control" })
    <strong>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File, null, new { @class = "label label-danger" })</strong>
</div>

<div class="form-group noleftpadding">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
}
```

Is there an easy way to process the percentage that the browser displays and apply it to the progress bar?

Comment: Can you show how you ended up using the function in your view please?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Do ajax progress handler do the job?

```
function uploadFile(){
    myApp.showPleaseWait(); //show dialog
    var file=document.getElementById('file_name').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file_name", file);
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "/to/action");
    ajax.send(formData);
}

function progressHandler(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    $('.bar').width(percent); //from bootstrap bar class
}

function completeHandler(){
    myApp.hidePleaseWait(); //hide dialog
    $('.bar').width(100);
}
```

Note: `myApp.showPleaseWait();` and `myApp.hidePleaseWait();` are defined in the [link](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1) provided by OP.

(edit: formData and formdata was previously inconsistent)

Comment: How do you use this in the view. Could you provide and example please?

Comment: View is in the twitter bootstrap [link](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1). I added the dialog show/hide on my post.

Comment: Easiest way to handle the progress bar. Thank you @vusan

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for another solution here it is:

```
function showPleaseWait() {

    if (document.querySelector("#pleaseWaitDialog") == null) {
        var modalLoading = '<div class="modal" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">\
        <div class="modal-dialog">\
            <div class="modal-content">\
                <div class="modal-header">\
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Please wait...</h4>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                    <div class="progress">\
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"\
                      aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%; height: 40px">\
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
        $(document.body).append(modalLoading);
    }

    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
}

/**
 * Hides "Please wait" overlay. See function showPleaseWait().
 */
function hidePleaseWait() {
    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
}
 $('#load').click(function () {
    showPleaseWait();
});
```

And call it like this :

```
<button id="load">Load It!</button>
```

if you want to hide it make sure to call `hidePleaseWait()` after success.