# How to check if my current processing request is completed in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, onunload

I have a reporting web application in MVC. In one of the part, there is is file upload feature!! 
File upload is not made up as Modal pop up which disables everything in background but it's a simple view.

I need to check the file load status if user clicks on any other link in page ? So what approach should I use?  I would want to give user an alert (" File load is not complete!! Stay on this page or leave this page !!").

When I tried jquery unload: All my temp variables were lost(For eg: Tempdata) which could check the load status!! So what should be the best approach in an MVC application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545780/bootstrap-progress-bar-for-mvc-file-upload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page