# Changing parts of view dynamically based on controller response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I'm looking for best approach suggestions for the below scenario:

- A user can choose one or more csv files to validate(Attachment 1) which on "validate" button click goes through the validation code(showing progress bar till it returns an output).
- A return response is either a success message or the error details for each file chosen to validate(Attachment 2)
- A successfully validated file can now be uploaded to azure storage with an "Upload" button.

Attachment 1
[image]

Attachment 2
[image]

Now, to make everything **asynchronous**, my thought is that the view needs to have individual flexible section for each file.

I'm working with MVC5 razor views with knockout.js, I have decent idea about partial views but I am not certain on how to go about this. If not partial views, then what would be the best approach.

Comment: Do you upload all the files in a single request??

Comment: There is an "Upload" button corresponding to each file that was successfully  validated. Only those can be uploaded using one request at a time.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545780/bootstrap-progress-bar-for-mvc-file-upload

Comment: This sure helps but my main concern is on how the achieve the UI for each file, show/hide buttons, messages whereas keeping the same model and controller.

Comment: You can have a generic view page that displays file name, if uploading, the time left, else the upload button or validation message. Use a single partial view and fill values from controller

Comment: Again, how to achieve this? How would I know which file has user chosen to validate? How do i update just the model for this file, keeping other file models same as they were.

Comment: A "best approach" question without some initial code sounds a bit too much like "do my work" to me... Can you show us what you have/what you tried?

Comment: @user3297291, I am not asking for code but a written explanation as to how should i structure the html so that one file process is not affected or is affecting other file process stages.

Comment: Have you read any documentation or tutorials on the topic? Show us your research and ask more specific questions. Here's where you can get started: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my thought is that the view needs to have individual flexible section
>   for each file

Kind of, what I think you need is a separate model/class for the files in order to run ajax commands on demand, at least that's how I understood your explanation.

Check out this jsfiddle, I have added some random true/false and string stuff to try and mimic your layout as quickly as possible. For testing try to use 5 or more files (random generators are kind of finicky in JS).

https://jsfiddle.net/n2ne6yLh/10/

So essentially you listen for a change event on the file input. Map each file to a new model "FileModel" in this case, then push it into the observableArray Files. Each FileModel houses it's own individual results, validation functions etc. Then the layout takes care of the rest.

You will have need to look into the FormData Web API in order to do stuff with the files in Javascript. If your clients/users are using outdated browsers there a shims/polyfills for the FormData stuff, jquery and what have you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

```js
var PageModel = function(r) {
  var self = this;
  this.Files = ko.observableArray();
  this.FileErrors = ko.computed(function() {
    return _.some(self.Files(), function(file) {
      return file.IsValid() === false;
    });
  });
  this.ClearFiles = function() {
    document.getElementById("your-files").value = "";
    self.Files([]);
  };

  var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
  control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    // When the control has changed, there are new files
    var i = 0,
      files = control.files,
      len = files.length;
    var form = new FormData();

    for (; i < len; i++) {
      form.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
      self.Files.push(new FileModel(files[i], files[i]));
    }
  }, false);

}

var FileModel = function(r, fileObject) {
  var self = this;
  this.FileObject = fileObject;
  this.Name = r.name;
  this.Type = r.type;
  this.Size = r.size;

  this.IsValidated = ko.observable(false);
  this.IsValid = ko.observable();
  this.ValidationErrors = ko.observable();

  this.ValidateFile = function() {
    //Do some ajax to validate file
    //console.log('Doing an ajax thing.')

    // Randomizers for validation, remove in production
    var random_boolean = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    var random_strins = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

    // Set vals based on returned ajax response.
    self.IsValidated(true);
    self.IsValid(random_boolean);
    self.ValidationErrors(random_strins);
  };
  this.UploadFile = function() {
    alert('uploading this file to the interwebs, yay!')
  }
}

window.model = new PageModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="your-files" multiple>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: ClearFiles">Clear</button>
  </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h4>Validate Files</h4>
      <!-- ko if: Files().length > 0 -->
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Size (bytes)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- ko foreach: Files -->
          <tr data-bind="css: IsValid() ? 'success' : ''">
            <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Type"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Size"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bind="click: ValidateFile, visible: !IsValidated()">Validate</button>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bind="click: UploadFile, visible: IsValid()">Upload</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h4>File Errors</h4>
      <!-- ko if: FileErrors() -->
      <table class="table table-hovered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Error Message</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- ko foreach: Files -->
          <!-- ko if: IsValid() == false -->
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ValidationErrors"></td>
          </tr>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This really does what I was expecting, although i am looking for a pure razor approach using partial views. I'm more of an Angular js guy myself. I ll accept this as final answer if something in razor doesn't comes up. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following simple algorithm
Let's assume in your html you have a < div id="allFiles">

You can write the following in your main view file

```
 function validateFiles(filesToValidate)) {
    foreach(file in filesToValidate)
    {
        var fileDivWithIdTheNameOfTheFile = @Html.RenderPartial("A_View_WithProgressBar",file)  
        allFiles.AddElement(fileDivWithIdTheNameOfTheFile );
        ajax.Get("YourActionThatReturnsAResultView",file)
            .OnSuccess(args)
            {
                FindDivForCurrentFile.ReplaceWith(args.ResultView)
            }

     }
}
```

This way most of you code is on the ServerSide,all you need is some jquery code to replace parts of the page once a validation of a file has been completed

Answer (score 1):

Going with a partial view will work. Just have one partial view with the basic table layout for what you need. Then have

```
<div id='partial'/>
```

in your main form that is hidden. Post your file using knockout or jquery to your upload action. Let the action return your partial view. Then using knockout or jquery's success callback, do something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
             $('#partial').html(data);
          }
```

to insert your partial view's html