# Give browser access to directory for many file uploads

Tags: .net, file-upload, knockout.js

The project - a page that will allow a user to upload many files for access to many individual users in batch - user 1 will have access to file1.txt, user 2 will have access to file2.txt, etc.

The user will upload an excel file that contains the file name, the user ID, and various other details that will be added to a database for identification of the file.

The trick is finding the best way to upload the files to the browser and server.  The initial suggestion was a zip file that could be processed on the server, but that file could easily get huge but fast, not to mention the potential of timeouts if the number of files is large enough.

It sounds like it makes more sense to load the files to a local directory, pass that location to the browser, let it find the file in said directory, and process the upload. A series of single uploads means (I think) less chance of timeout.

I'm just not sure if I can pass a directory using the file field / upload control, or if there's a better control that meets my needs. I suspect could pass the path as a string, concatenate it to the file name in xls file, grab it and upload it...I think? I'm not sure if I can get access to the directory that way.

Current version of the page only allows single uploads, not in batch like I'm trying to do. Uses Knockout libraries for the front end, and I'm probably not going to be able to move to anything else.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The default HTML input field allows multiple uploads with the multiple flag. You just hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click while selecting files.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-multiple

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

See here for an example of uploading multiple files and using knockout.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831639/6069178

Comment: I may not have been clear - I'm trying to select a directory, in which there will be hundreds or more files that will be processed.  So I'm not as interested in saying "these are the files to process" as I am in saying "Here's the directory where all the files you will be processing will be"